# How to install librdkafka with Kerberos?

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, rhel7, confluent-platform

So I am trying to write a script where the data comes from a database and then gets published into a kafka topic. I am using the `confluent-kafka` due to its speed.
The kafka has `kerberos` configured thus, I have to enable it in my producer. I have the keytab and the required config parameters.

As far as I understand I need to manually install `librdkafka` + it's dependencies and then install the `confluent-kafka` from source.

So till now I have installed the following dependencies:

```
1. yum install cyrus-sasl.
2. yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
3. yum install cyrus-sasl-lib
4. yum install cyrus-sasl-gssapi
5. yum install openssl-devel
6. yum install openssl
```

When I try to execute the following command `yum install librdkafka` it gives me as error:

```
No package librdkafka. Error: Nothing to do
```

I was hoping this would install `librdkafka` and then I could execute the following command `pip install --no-binary :all: confluent-kafka` and get the `confluent-kafka` working with `kerberos`.

1. Could anyone tell me if I am doing this right as I haven't been able to find any guide regarding this.
2. I may also be missing some dependencies, if that is the case feel free to point it out.
3. Lastly, if my procedure till now or for the future is flawed, do point it out and please advise how to go about it.

System Info:

> OS: rhel-7-server

P.S If there are any additional info required, let me know I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: If the data is from a database, Kafka Connect framework is usually what people use

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of librdkafka is not generally available in RHEL, you should use the Confluent RPM repository to get the most up to date version.

1. Add the [Confluent RPM repository](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html)
2. Install librdkafka devel packages: `yum install librdkafka-devel`
3. Build and install the [confluent-kafka-python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) client with `python setup.py install` or `pip install .`

Comment: I added the Confluent RPM repository.  But it still says 

`No package librdkafka-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do`